# HTTP authentication is wrongfuly enabled on a server after i copied some files from that server to another

Tags: apache-2.2, http

I have the strangest problem. Like the title says, I've moved some files from the first server to the second, i had http auth on the second server and now i have http auth on the first server but not on the second. That's right, I haven't uploaded any files from what i know on the first server. There are no .htpasswds files or .htaccess files to enforce http auth on the first server now.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP Auth should be configured in the Apache configuration file. It should only be configured in the .htaccess file if you do not have access to the Apache configuration file. Therefore, if you know that you have no .htaccess file in the directory in question, it only seems logical that your Auth is being implemented in the Apache conf file. Take a look there - in the Directory stanza for the DocumentRoot in question.

Depending on your distro (I am assuming Linux here) you may find your conf file in /etc/httpd or /etc/apache2

If you find Auth directives in the conf file, remove them or comment them our by prepending # in front of the lines, and then restart Apache. Again, depending on your distro, the Apache restart may be any of the following:

```
service apache2 restart
service httpd restart
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Comment: thanks, i've checked, but this was not the issue, my conf files were fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away after i restored all the content from the backups i had. I've checked what jdw said but that wasn't it, my httpd.conf did not have such things. One thing worth noting, though, is that my FTP client(Filezilla) had the transfer mode set to ASCII, which removed line feeds from the transfered files. This could have been one of the reasons for my strange situation, but i doubt it accounts for all of it.